# StrongLoop grunt task and slc controller

Tags: express, gruntjs, strongloop

How can I switch datastores depending on the current instance type?
For example: 
Take Instance types: PRODUCTION, TEST1, TEST2;
I would like that my model(s) to switch from PROD_MONGO Data Store to 
TEST1_MONGO or TEST2_MONGO stores, depending on some command line option or some grunt option, determined at runtime.

My question is somewhat related to [What is the different between using StrongLoop's "slc run" and "node app.js"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247071/what-is-the-different-between-using-strongloops-slc-run-and-node-app-js)

In addition to changing datastore backends, I'd be quite happy to log into different destinations / files. http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/SLC/Application+logging

I'd be quite happy to check how one of the many Grunt Express modules can work with my StrongLoop project. I was just hoping there is some example of doing this that I might have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the first question, but you might be looking for environment specific configurations? See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Environment-specific+configuration

For logging into different locations, the doc you pointed at explains what you can do.

As for examples, I maintain a full list of examples here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example

If you have any more specific questions, feel free to ask. ;)

Comment: I'm sure I've come accross that article, but I did not make the connection. Many thanks for your quick answer! Also I've found this article about creating datasources programatically http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Advanced+topics%3A+data+sources.