# Monitor for changes and restart server in Strongloop app

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I just started working on an existing app using Strongloop. To run the server, I use:

```
NODE_ENV=staging-local DEBUG=middleware:* slc run
```

I want to monitor for any changes in my application and automatically restart the server on change. I have used tools like `nodemon` which accomplishes this but I want to know how to best do this with strongloop.

Comment: Why can't you use nodemon?

Comment: I was reading `slc run` provides more features than `node app` (or `nodemon`) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247071/what-is-the-different-between-using-strongloops-slc-run-and-node-app-js. I figured I would just stick to the convention used by the project also.

Comment: Right, and with nodemon you can still use `slc run`

Comment: I don't think the features slc run provides really help you very much with development, unless it has changed significantly since i last used it.

Comment: Doh ... you're right. If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything better specifically for loopback applications, but nodemon isn't just for node; it can be used to start any process, so it should have no problem running `slc run` for you.